# Syntax error when compiling vlc media player

Tags: video

I try to compile vlc, but I always get this syntax error:

```
Unterminated quoted string

make: *** [.a52] error 2

contribs:make failed

cd a52dec && CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm" CXX="arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm" LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld" AR="arm-linux-androideabi-ar" CCAS="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -c" RANLIB="arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib" STRIP="arm-linux-androideabi-strip" PATH="/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/bin:/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin:/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin:/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386/bin"
:/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/contrib/contrib-android-arm-linux-androideabi/../arm-linux-androideabi/bin" CPPFLAGS=" -g -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -I/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include -I/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -I/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/include" CFLAGS=" -g -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -I/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include -I/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -I/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/include -g" CXXFLAGS=" -g -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -I/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include -I/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -I/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/include -g" LDFLAGS=" -L/home/timliu/test/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a -lgnustl_static -L/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/lib" ./configure --prefix="/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi" --datarootdir="/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share" --includedir="/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/include" --libdir="/home/timliu/net/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/lib" --build="i686-linux-gnu" --host="arm-linux-androideabi" --target="arm-linux-androideabi" --program-prefix="" --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking --with-pic
contribs: make failed
```

My specifications:

- OS: (Ubuntu 14.04 32bit) linux ubuntu 3.13.0-32 generic 2014 i686
- NDK: android-ndk-r10e
- JDK: adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702 32bit
- java-version: "1.7.0-79" | 
  OpenJDK runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-Oubuntu0.14.04.2)
- vlc: 
  git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc-ports/android.git

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about compiling vlc (a programming issue).

Comment: Agreed. It should be on the vlc forum instead

Comment: If this question is closed. Then we should also close all the "how to compile ffmpeg" spam.

Comment: @Volodya Could you please write a meta post for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. An error happens due to environment variables.

I added :`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386` to `etc/profile`

```
export JAHA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386
```

Now , I can compile libvlc, but new problem arises:

```
libvlc:compileReleaseJava FAILED
*what went wrong:
Execution failed for task 'libvlc:compileReleaseJAVA'.
> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and config used your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according dirctory.
```